# Why do I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf' error when I run pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

here is the structure of my project:
[image]

When I run my unit test: test_search_file_aucun_fichier
I have the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'

Here is my test:

```
import unitest
import os
import sys
from Ecarts.applis.aoc.echange.module.calculRegFi.BriqueReglementFinancier.conf import *
from Ecarts.applis.aoc.echange.module.calculRegFi import *
from Ecarts.applis.aoc.echange.module.calculRegFi.BriqueReglementFinancier.fonctions import 
search_file 

class FonctionsTest(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_search_file_aucun_fichier(self):
   path_test = os.getcwd() + "/data"
   os.chdir(path_test)
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
        search_file(name_pattern='param_RegFi_' + '[0-9]'*4 + '.csv',type='paramètres')
    self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

I tried several solutions:
import sys
sys.path.append ('../../')
import config

But it does not work!
i have :
[image]

```html
test_fonctions_tua.py:None (test_fonctions_tua.py)
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\nleymarie\mecapa\Ecarts-Python\Ecarts\applis\aoc\echange\module\calculRegFi\tests\tua\fonctions\test_fonctions_tua.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:571: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.fspath, mode=importmode)
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:517: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
C:\Users\nleymarie\Library\Python3.6.5\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:994: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:971: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:955: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:665: in _load_unlocked
    ???
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:171: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
test_fonctions_tua.py:6: in <module>
    from Ecarts.applis.aoc.echange.module.calculRegFi.BriqueReglementFinancier.fonctions import search_file
..\..\..\BriqueReglementFinancier\fonctions.py:12: in <module>
    from conf import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please insert the full stacktrace _as code_, not image. Also, `test_search_file_aucun_fichier` is not present in your folder structure. Please try to remove unnecessary elements and stick to what is the seemingly relevant data. If it's an importing error, you can most likely isolate it

Comment: When accessing *conf* from *fonctions.py*, you need to use the full import qualifier (`from Ecarts.applis.….conf import *`).